# Unexpected animation glitch related to scroll to top?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit

First of all, sorry that this is not a very generic question (it's pretty specific) but I'm knocking my head against the wall on this one and can't find anything (obviously).

So I have built this library to swipe away a stack of cards based on a `UICollectionView`, and everything works fine, except for **when I tap the status bar to "scroll-to-top" and then try to swipe a card away, the animation somehow does something weird** I can't explain nor understand. 
Another thing that happens is at the bottom the animation also screws up, bot I don't think that's related to this and probably has something to do with the custom `flowlayout`.

You can find the **source code** on [Github here](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper)

Here's the Github issue with some more info:
https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper/issues/4

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!
Have a nice day :)

here's a demo:

[image: demo]

Here are some of the most important code snippets (I think):

*CardCell:*

```
/// The CardCell that the user can swipe away. Based on `UICollectionViewCell`.
class CardCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CardCellSwipeDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var positionLbl: UILabel!

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        // make sure anchorPoint is correct when laying out subviews.
        self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    /**
     We use this function to calculate and set a random backgroundcolor.
     */
    public func setRandomBackgroundColor(){

        let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
        let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
        let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    /**
     This function animates the card. The animation consists of a rotation and translation.
     - parameter angle: The angle the card rotates while animating.
     - parameter horizontalTranslation: The horizontal translation the card animates in.
     */
    public func animateCard(angle: CGFloat, horizontalTranslation: CGFloat){

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 0, 1)
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, horizontalTranslation, 0, 1)
        layer.transform = transform
    }

    /**
     Resets the CardCell back to the center of the CollectionView.
    */
    public func resetToCenterPosition(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })
    }

    /**
     Called when the pan gesture is ended.
     Handles what happens when the user stops swiping a card.
     If a certain treshold of the screen is swiped, the `animateOffScreen` function is called,
     if the threshold is not reached, the card will be reset to the center by calling `resetToCenterPosition`.
     - parameter direction: The direction of the pan gesture.
     - parameter centerX: The center X point of the swipeAbleArea/collectionView.
     - parameter angle: The angle of the animation, depends on the direction of the swipe.
    */
    public func endedPanAnimation(withDirection direction: PanDirection, centerX: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat){

        let swipePercentageMargin = self.bounds.width * 0.4
        let cardCenter = self.convert(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY), to: self.superview)

        if (cardCenter.x > centerX + swipePercentageMargin || cardCenter.x < centerX - swipePercentageMargin){
            animateOffScreen(angle: angle)
        } else {
            self.resetToCenterPosition()
        }
    }

    /**
     Animates to card off the screen and calls the `didSwipeAway` function from the `CardCellSwipeDelegate`.
     - parameter angle: The angle that the card will rotate in (depends on direction). Positive means the card is swiped to the right, a negative angle means the card is swiped to the left.
    */
    fileprivate func animateOffScreen(angle: CGFloat){

        var direction: CellSwipeDirection = .None

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 0, 1)

        // swipe left
        if angle < 0 {
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -(self.frame.width * 2), 0, 1)
            direction = .Left
        }

        // swipe right
        if angle > 0 {
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, (self.frame.width * 2), 0, 1)
            direction = .Right
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in

            self?.layer.transform = transform
        })
        delegate?.didSwipeAway(cell: self, swipeDirection: direction)
    }

    /**
     Prepares for reuse by resetting the anchorPoint back to the default value.
     This is necessary because in HomeVC we are manipulating the anchorPoint during dragging animation.
    */
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // reset to default value (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint)
        self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }
}
```

*flowlayout:*

```
/// Custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that provides the flowlayout information like paging and `CardCell` movements.
class VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    /// This property sets the amount of scaling for the first item.
    public var firstItemTransform: CGFloat?
    /// This property enables paging per card. The default value is true.
    public var isPagingEnabled: Bool = true
    /// Stores the height of a CardCell.
    internal var cellHeight: CGFloat!

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        assert(collectionView!.numberOfSections == 1, "Number of sections should always be 1.")
        assert(collectionView!.isPagingEnabled == false, "Paging on the collectionview itself should never be enabled. To enable cell paging, use the isPagingEnabled property of the VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout instead.")
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let items = NSArray (array: super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!, copyItems: true)

        items.enumerateObjects(using: { (object, index, stop) -> Void in
            let attributes = object as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

            self.updateCellAttributes(attributes)
        })
        return items as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    }

    /**
     Updates the attributes.
     Here manipulate the zIndex of the cards here, calculate the positions and do the animations.
     - parameter attributes: The attributes we're updating.
    */
    func updateCellAttributes(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        let minY = collectionView!.bounds.minY + collectionView!.contentInset.top
        let maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y

        let finalY = max(minY, maxY)
        var origin = attributes.frame.origin
        let deltaY = (finalY - origin.y) / attributes.frame.height

        if let itemTransform = firstItemTransform {
            let scale = 1 - deltaY * itemTransform
            attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            // TODO: add card stack effect (like Shazam)
        }
        origin.y = finalY
        attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: attributes.frame.size)
        attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
    }

    // We invalidate the layout when a "bounds change" happens, for example when we scale the top cell. This forces a layout update on the flowlayout.
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Cell paging
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        // If the property `isPagingEnabled` is set to false, we don't enable paging and thus return the current contentoffset.
        guard isPagingEnabled else {
            let latestOffset = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
            return latestOffset
        }

        // Page height used for estimating and calculating paging.
        let pageHeight = cellHeight + self.minimumLineSpacing

        // Make an estimation of the current page position.
        let approximatePage = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y/pageHeight

        // Determine the current page based on velocity.
        let currentPage = (velocity.y < 0.0) ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage)

        // Create custom flickVelocity.
        let flickVelocity = velocity.y * 0.3

        // Check how many pages the user flicked, if <= 1 then flickedPages should return 0.
        let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)

        // Calculate newVerticalOffset.
        let newVerticalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * pageHeight) - self.collectionView!.contentInset.top

        return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: newVerticalOffset)
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        // make sure the zIndex of the next card is higher than the one we're swiping away.
        let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndexPath.row + 1, section: itemIndexPath.section)
        let nextAttr = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: nextIndexPath)
        nextAttr?.zIndex = nextIndexPath.row

        // attributes for swiping card away
        let attr = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: itemIndexPath)

        return attr
    }
}
```

Comment: In `func didSwipeAway(cell: CardCell, swipeDirection direction: CellSwipeDirection)` You call `performBatchUpdates` which has implicit animations. My guess would be that under certain circumstances it is setting the transform of the cell you've animated off. You can call your delegate method in the completion block of the transform animation and see the card animate back after it's gone completely offscreen. You might try snapshotting and hiding the original cell. So the implicit animation is applied to a hidden view.

Comment: I just tried without the performBatchUpdates and that didn't seem to fix it (it actually made the flowlayout somehow break after swiping a few cards away) I do appreciate the suggestion. Also, wouldn't it always happen then and not just when tapping the statusbar? Thanks again though

Comment: just read the second part of your comment (somehow missed it?) I'll look into it further, what you're saying makes a lot of sense!

Comment: If you move the delegate callback to the completion, you might try setting the layer opacity to 0 in the animation completion then setting back to 1 in `prepareForReuse` probably easier than dealing with snapshot views.

Comment: If I do what you described above then I get the animation glitch on every cell, so you're probably right in what you're saying, I'm just going to have to find a way to make it work. I'm already glad I know where to look now. Will probably try the snapshot method tomorrow. Thanks again for your help, it's a frustrating one.

Comment: @beyowulf You were right! I fixed it by surrounding it with `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` and then I realised I could just hide the card right before calling the delegate and unhiding it in `prepareForReuse` if you want you could still post the answer, I'll accept it. Thank you very much for helping me out!